# Computing the gradient of $(X,Y) \mapsto\dfrac{1}{2} \left\lVert A - XY^{T} \right\rVert _{F}^{2}$ via chain rule

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$. Consider the function
\begin{equation}
H \left( X , Y \right) := \dfrac{1}{2} \left\lVert A - XY^{T} \right\rVert _{F}^{2} ,
\end{equation}
where $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert _{F}$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

The first one seems to be easy.
I used the chain rule to get
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{X} H \left( X , Y \right) = \left( A - XY^{T} \right) \nabla_{X} \left( - XY^{T} \right) = - \left( A - XY^{T} \right) Y^{T} .
\end{equation}

For the second one, as $A - XY^{T} = A - \left( X^{T}Y \right) ^{T}$, we have
\begin{align}
\nabla_{Y} H \left( X , Y \right) = \left( \left( A - XY^{T} \right) \nabla_{Y} \left( - \left( X^{T}Y \right) ^{T} \right) \right) ^{T} & = \left( - \left( A - XY^{T} \right) X^{T} \right) ^{T} \\
& = - X \left( A - XY^{T} \right) ^{T} .
\end{align}

> Is my $\nabla_{Y} H \left( X , Y \right)$ formula correct?
>
> And is there other approaches to compute the gradient. I guess we can compute $H \left( X + \delta X , Y \right)$ then deduce the gradient from the difference $H \left( X + \delta X , Y \right) - H \left( X , Y \right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$
B = (XY^T-A) \implies
dB = (dX\,Y^T+X\,dY^T) 
$$
Write the function in terms of $B$, then find its differential and gradients.
$$\eqalign{
 H &= \tfrac{1}{2}B:B \cr
dH &= B:dB \cr
 &= B:dX\,Y^T &+ \,\,B:X\,dY^T \cr
 &= B:dX\,Y^T &+ \,\,B^T:dY\,X^T \cr
 &= BY:dX &+ \,\,B^TX:dY \cr
\frac{\partial H}{\partial X} &= BY, \quad
\frac{\partial H}{\partial Y} &= B^TX \cr
}$$
where the colon product is a convenient notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
M:N &= {\rm Tr}(M^TN)
}$$
Depending on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), these gradients might need to be transposed.

---

Your first solution has a problem (in red)
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial H}{\partial X} &= BY^T = X\color{red}{Y^TY^T} - AY^T \cr
}$$
In matrix calculus, terms involving the transpose are invariably of the form $Y^TY$ or $YY^T$

Your second solution is $XB^T$ but it should be $B^TX$.

To get a better handle on these transpose issues, I recommend that you work through the problem in which all of the matrices are rectangular, i.e. 
$$
A \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n}, \quad
X \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times r}, \quad
Y \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times r}  
$$
Then the solution to the current problem can be recovered by setting $m=n$.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. now it makes more sense since, at some point when I consider $H(Z,Z)$ and try to compute its gradients, my solution cause some trouble but your solution gives $\left( B + B^{T} \right) X$ which I think should be correct now